# blank page after of making project by create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I want to build my project with create react app. But, I encounter a blank page, when I run "yarn start" in project's directory. As others have said, I set "homepage": "." . but that does not work.

Some said router should be set to "hashrouter". Unfortunately, I don't understand how to do that.

This is my code that has used of context for building "themeSwitcher".

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './app.css';
import {themeContext} from './context.js';

function themeSwitcher(){
    return (
        <themeContext.consumer>
            {({Theme,changeTheme}) => (
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={Theme === "dark"}
                    onChange={() => changeTheme(Theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark")}
                />
            )}
        </themeContext.consumer>
    );
}

class app extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Theme: "light",
        changeTheme: this.changeTheme
    };
}
changeTheme = (Theme) => {
    this.setState({
        Theme
    });
};

render() {
    return (
         <themeContext.provider value={this.state}>
              <div>
                  <p>this is a switcher theme</p>
                  <span>Dark mode</span>
                  <themeSwitcher />
              </div>
         </themeContext.provider>
    );
}
}



ReactDOM.render(<app />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

context.js:

```
import React from "react";

export const themeContext = React.createContext({
    Theme: "light",
    changeTheme: () => {}
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add codes of context.js also. and while writting codes please write file name above  it. like ./App.js,  ./context.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are the components written with small letters? Component names must begin with a capital letter.

If possible then present code from './context.js'

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './app.css'
import { ThemeContext } from './context.js'

function ThemeSwitcher() {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {({ theme, toggleTheme }) => (
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={theme === 'dark'}
          onChange={toggleTheme}
        />
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      theme: 'light'
    }
  }

  toggleTheme = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      theme:
        state.theme === 'dark'
          ? 'light'
          : 'dark',
    }));
  }

  contextValue = {
    theme: this.state.theme,
    toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.contextValue}>
        <div>
          <p>this is a switcher theme</p>
          <span>Dark mode</span>
          <ThemeSwitcher />
        </div>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

You can also use hooks and functional components. The code is cleaner.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './app.css'
import { ThemeContext } from './context.js'

const ThemeSwitcher = () => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {({ theme, toggleTheme }) => (
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={theme === 'dark'}
        onChange={toggleTheme}
      />
    )}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
)

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light')

  const toggleTheme = () => setTheme(theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')

  const contextValue = {
    toggleTheme,
    theme,
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <div>
        <p>this is a switcher theme</p>
        <span>Dark mode</span>
        <ThemeSwitcher />
      </div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

context.js code

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";

export const ThemeContext = createContext({
    theme: "light",
    toggleTheme: () => {}
});
```

Comment: I change "app" to "App" & "themeSwitcher" to "ThemeSwitcher". but give me this error!!! "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. " @IvanPopov

Comment: should not use camelCase format for context's name? since this defined by "const" in "context.js". @Ivan

Comment: thank you! in your first code, in contextValue object, shoud not be "toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme" instead "toggleTheme"??? or not at all, it could not be that i transfer "toggleTheme" to state, and then i set <themeContext.Provider value={this.state}?@Ivan

Comment: @arman 
Yes you are right. I was not attentive. Corrected the code, and corrected context.js.

Comment: @arman 
I would not pass the whole state. And I pass the contextValue, which contains the values ​​for working with the theme. This is so that if something unrelated to the theme appears in the state, then it will not be passed to the ThemeContext.

Comment: @arman I'm used to creating variables that store data for the context, which are directly related to the context. Indeed, in the future, when the application grows, your state will be supplemented with new values ​​and they may have nothing to do with the theme and, accordingly, I see no reason to pass them into the context of the theme.

Comment: @arman You can do what is best for you. Hope I helped.)